# ¿Cómo funciona/se usa la función free en C?

Tags: c

Se que `free` se usa para liberar memoria asignada por `malloc`, `calloc`... pero no sé muy bien a qué se refiere eso o el uso que se le puede dar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nota inicial:** La respuesta que voy a dar es a grandes rasgos. No intenta ser especialmente precisa y exacta ya que algunos detalles dependerán del Sistema Operativo y de la arquitectura hardware (por ejemplo existencia de paginación / segmentación, memoria virtual, ...).

Un programa en C tiene, a grandes rasgos, dos opciones a la hora de requerir memoria para almacenar valores: el *stack* (la pila) y el *heap* (memoria dinámica).

La pila es una zona de memoria de tamaño límitado que funciona como una pila LIFO. Las llamadas a funciones, por ejemplo, se registran aquí para que el programa sepa volver al punto inicial después de ejecutar una función.

En la pila también se pueden almacenar variables y suele ser de lo primero que se aprende:

```
int main()
{
  int var; // Variable creada en la pila
}
```

Algunos inconvenientes de la pila, por citar algunos son los siguientes:

- Su tamaño es limitado y no se puede incrementar una vez ejecutado el programa... suele suceder mientras aprendes te equivocas al programar una función recursiva y acabas obteniendo un error del tipo *stack overflow*. Esto sucede porque la pila se ha llenado con las llamadas recursivas y el programa se aborta. Que el tamaño sea limitado impide que se pueda almacenar en la misma objetos demasiado grandes (como por ejemplo ficheros).
- Compartir memoria entre diferentes funciones puede requerir copiar dicha información de forma recurrente, lo cual es engorroso y consume tiempo.

Para los casos en los que la pila no resuelve nuestro problema tenemos que recurrir a la memoria dinámica. Para ello el Sistema Operativo (en adelante SO) pone a tu disposición fragmentos de la memoria RAM del equipo. ¿Cómo se solicita uno de esos fragmentos? En el caso de C con `malloc` o con `realloc`. Estas funciones hablan con el SO para solicitar memoria RAM y es el propio SO el que hace la reserva y les indica dónde está ubicada dicha reserva (el puntero que te devuelven dichas funciones).

Mientras la reserva está en vigor ningún otro programa podrá hacer uso de dicha memoria. Para evitar que un programa llegue a acaparar de forma innecesaria toda la memoria del equipo es necesario liberar aquella que ya no es necesaria y para eso se recurre a la función `free`.

`free` habla con el SO y le comunica que una de las reservas de memoria que te pertenecen se puede liberar, por lo que la memoria asociada a dicha reserva puede quedar a disposición de cualquier otro proceso.

Ahora un caso práctico:

```
int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    int* ptr = (int*)malloc(1000*sizeof(int));

    // operaciones sobre ptr...
  }
}
```

Si ejecutas este código ¿qué sucede? Si lo ejecutas y abres el gestor de recursos del sistema verás como la memoria disponible se consume rápidamente hasta llegar a 0. El ordenador empezará a ir cada vez más lento hasta que la aplicación finalmente se cierre al no poder reservar más memoria.

Sin embargo si ahora ejecutamos este otro código:

```
int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    int* ptr = (int*)malloc(1000*sizeof(int));

    // operaciones sobre ptr

    free(ptr);
  }
}
```

Veremos como el nivel de memoria disponible en el equipo permanece en un nivel estable. El programa ahora es capaz de realizar reservas de memoria y de liberar dichas reservas, lo que evita que el sistema se quede sin recursos.

Posibles usos de la memoria dinámica:

- creación de árboles y listas. Los sistemas con una cantidad indeterminada de nodos suelen implementarse con memoria dinámica debido a la flexibilidad que proporciona dicha zona de la memoria (y a que no hay restricciones de tamaño).
- recursos del SO. Muchos de los recursos que el SO pone a tu disposición de ubican en la memoria dinámica. En estos casos lo normal es que el SO te devuelva un identificador, de tal forma que ni eres consciente del uso de la memoria dinámica ni tampoco puedes gestionarla directamente... pero ahí está.
- Compartición de recursos: Cuando se desean compartir recursos entre diferentes procesos o a nivel global en la aplicación se suele recurrir a la memoria dinámica para tener más control sobre el ciclo de vida de dichos recursos.